# Numpy Logspace - Why No Negatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to easily create arrays on a log scale and I have used

```
for c in [np.logspace(1,3,num = 3, base=10, dtype=int)]:
    print(c)
```

which works succesfully for positive exponents. However, what if I want to start from negative exponents i.e. 0.01? Why does

```
for c in [np.logspace(-2,3,num = 6, base=10, dtype=int)]:
    print(c)
```

produce:

```
[   0    0    1   10  100 1000]
```

rather than

```
[   0.01    0.1    1   10  100 1000]
```

and most importantly is there a way to get the above result with a numpy or similar library rather than using something like this:

```
[10**i for i in range(-2,3)]
```

Comment: Your data type is `int`. If you represent a decimal as an integer, it gets truncated.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be related to your question, but you really don't need a loop here. You're not looping over the numpy array, you're iterating over the one-element list you're creating around that array, and printing the whole array in one go. I'd suggest either getting rid of the square brackets (so that you *do* loop over the array), or just doing `print(np.logspace(...))` directly, without any loop at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `np.logspace()` you added a `dtype=int` keyword argument, which makes the function only return integers.

Just remove that argument:

```
np.logspace(-2, 3, num=6, base=10)
>>>array([1.e-02, 1.e-01, 1.e+00, 1.e+01, 1.e+02, 1.e+03])
```

Comment: No problem happy to help :)